# PHP uploading photos gets a url "[Deprecation]" error

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to create an upload photo feature in my CMS, but if I click on my "upload" button, I get the "Deprecation" error, preventing me to see if my code has any mistakes or if successful.

**Full Error:** (saw in developer tools)

> [Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed
>   whitespace (\n,\r, \t) characters and less-than characters
>   (<) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than
>   characters from places like element attribute values in order to load
>   these resources. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more
>   details.

The error says my url could contain removed whitespace and less-than characters, but my url in my page is: `"localhost/infinitygroup/cms/for_lease_photos_list.php?i=1"`. `"i=1"` is just the unique id in SQL.

Would like to know why error is happening.

**Interface:**

[image: Interface]

**Button:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 spacer">
    <div class="spacer"><strong>Upload a Photo</strong></div>
        <form action="for_lease_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <input type="file" name="file">
              <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
         </form>
         <br>
   </div>
```

**Upload Photo Code on Button Click**

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //input type file
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.',$fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
      if ($fileError ===  0) {
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = '/img/_uploads/lease/details/'.$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
        // header("Location: ");
      } else {
        echo "File upload error!";
      }
    } else {
      echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
    }
```

UPDATE:

Took the advice of a comment belo. I checked the "Network" in developer tools and there are no "whitespace" or "less than signs".

[image: 2]

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: my url involves a bit of SQL

Comment: `$fileDestination` should be system path `eg: var/www/xxx`

Comment: Is that bit of SQL part of the problem here? If it is, we need to see it.

Comment: What is the `upload` button type of which you speak?? There are 3 types you can use `button`,`reset` and `submit`

Comment: try `$fileDestination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/_uploads/lease/details/'.$fileNameNew;`

Comment: @RamRaider my upload button is "<button type="upload" name="upload">Upload</button>"

Comment: @Gulshan thank you for the suggestion but i get the same "[Deprecation]" error

Comment: `type="upload"` doesn't exist! Should be `type="submit"`

Comment: agree with @kerbholz

Comment: switched all "upload" to "submit" the "[Deprecation]" error still stays

Comment: I don't think the error is triggered by any of the code you've shared. Look at the Network tab if the browser's developer tools, reload the page, then look for URLs that match the pattern described by the error message. The only URL in the question is `for_lease_upload` which doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: @Quentin tried your advice, I updated it in the question

Comment: Go through each one and look at the full URL, not just the name component of it (which is the bit listed on the left-hand side of the screenshot).

Comment: went through each one, the URLs do not have removed whitespace or a less than sign